# ADOdb Lite versus MySqli

Tags: php, mysqli, adodb

I am working an a project to build an arcade site with PHP. I am considering using ADOdb Lite or MySqli. Which one is better for performance, speed and security?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

mysqli is the [MySQL recommended API for interacting with a MySQL database, and in active development](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php#mysqli.overview.mysqlnd). [the last version of ADOdb Lite is from 2007-01-12](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adodblite/files/). i would quite clearly choose mysqli.